# Why does top not require root (can non-root programs see other running processes)?

Tags: command-line, permissions

I've been trying to figure out if an app that is not run as root has access to a list of running programs on the system. I would assume the answer is no, but haven't been able to find anything about it. It seems odd to me that the `top` command doesn't require root, which would suggest that any app could also gain access to this command.

Is there a way around this? I assume it would be possible to just set the permissions of /usr/bin/top to root?

Answer (score 3):

On Linux it's traditional for all users to be able to see the list of running processes.  While it does reveal information about what software is running and what privileges it's running as, it's not traditionally considered a primary security risk.

You can configure it so that users can't see the process list, though it may break compatibility with some applications.

More info at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244353/why-can-i-list-other-users-processes-without-root-permission

Answer (score 2):

In case of Ubuntu and Linux distros, everything has to do with `/proc` filesystem , where each process has directory that matches its pid and files that list information about the process. Most of the information is publicly accessible, such as process names, memory statistics, etc. This is also easy to see with `strace -e trace=open top -b -n1` command, which will tell you that `top` opens whole bunch of directories and files in `/proc` for reading.

> It seems odd to me that the top command doesn't require root, which would suggest that any app could also gain access to this command.

The key here is that you need access to the system in the first place. If you are a user on a system, there's no reason to hide other processes from you, since security through obscurity never works.

> Is there a way around this? I assume it would be possible to just set the permissions of /usr/bin/top to root?

You can set permissions of `top`, except that won't prevent other programs from accessing information about running processes.

You can set mounting options for `/proc` in `/etc/fstab` file with `hidepid` option. From `man proc`:

Mount options
       The proc filesystem supports the following mount options:

```
   hidepid=n (since Linux 3.3)
          This option controls who can access the information in
          /proc/[pid] directories.  The argument, n, is one of the
          following values:

          0   Everybody may access all /proc/[pid] directories.  This is
              the traditional behavior, and the default if this mount
              option is not specified.

          1   Users may not access files and subdirectories inside any
              /proc/[pid] directories but their own (the /proc/[pid]
              directories themselves remain visible).  Sensitive files
              such as /proc/[pid]/cmdline and /proc/[pid]/status are now
              protected against other users.  This makes it impossible
              to learn whether any user is running a specific program
              (so long as the program doesn't otherwise reveal itself by
              its behavior).

          2   As for mode 1, but in addition the /proc/[pid] directories
              belonging to other users become invisible.  This means
              that /proc/[pid] entries can no longer be used to discover
              the PIDs on the system.  This doesn't hide the fact that a
              process with a specific PID value exists (it can be
              learned by other means, for example, by "kill -0 $PID"),
              but it hides a process's UID and GID, which could
              otherwise be learned by employing stat(2) on a /proc/[pid]
              directory.  This greatly complicates an attacker's task of
              gathering information about running processes (e.g.,
              discovering whether some daemon is running with elevated
              privileges, whether another user is running some sensitive
              program, whether other users are running any program at
              all, and so on).
```

Thus , what you probably want is to have something like this in `/etc/fstab`:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults,hidepid=2        0       0
```

There is also `gid` option, where you could allow certain group of users to see the process info, such as admin group. The `gid` are numeric, so you would use something like `gid=1000` to allow only your admin user and other users who belong to his group to see process information.

You could also temporarily remount `/proc` filesystem like so (for testing or other purposes):

```
mount -o remount,hidepid=2 /proc
```